# How to prove $F(z)$ is bounded and holomorphic? A question from 《fourier analysis and nonlinear partial differential equations》

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

[image]
[image]
May be the picture can not be unfold, this question below is  in **page11** of book ***Fourier analysis and and nonlinear partial differential analysis*** Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin.
When we study harmonic analysis, Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem is very important. The proof of Riese-Thorin complex interpolation is easy because we just consider simple functions, and we can easily conclude that $F(z)$ in the following picture is analytic because $a_{k}^{P(z)}b_{j}^{Q(z)}$ is analytic($a_{k}$ and $b_{j}$ are **constant**).
[image]

But, in the above picture, how can we prove that $F(z)$ is holomophic and bounded(**note that in the above picture, the author does not use simple functions**)?

Any hints are wellcome thanks everyone who read this question!!!

Comment: This feels like it would use the theorem about differentiation under the integral sign for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Thank you @BrunoB. I can't agree with you more! But in this place, how to deal with $Af_{z}$, where $A$ is a linear bounded operator from $L^{p_{j}}(X_{1};L^{q_{j}}(X_{2}))$ to $L^{r_{j}}(X_{3})$,$j\in\{0,1\}$. How $z$ depends on $Af_{z}$, After all, there does not exact formula about $Af_{z}$.

Comment: If you write $g : z \mapsto f_z$, and assuming $g$ is holomorphic, then $A \circ g : z \mapsto A(f_z)$ is holomorphic too by linearity and continuity of $A$. To see this you can use the equivalence between weak and strong holomorphicity: for any $\Lambda$ in the (continuous) dual of $L^{r_\theta}(X_3)$, which I'll note $(L^{r_\theta}(X_3))^*$, $\Lambda \circ A$ belongs in $(L^{p_\theta}(X_1 ; L^{q_\theta}(X_2)))^*$, thus $(\Lambda \circ A) \circ g = \Lambda \circ (A \circ g)$ is holomorphic. But this applies to any $\Lambda \in (L^{r_\theta}(X_3))^*$, hence $A \circ g$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I get your idea!!! Best wishes!